# how to convert sentence to bulleted list in laravel 4

Tags: arrays, json, laravel-4

Is it possible to convert sentence in bullet list in laravel. I have a form that inputs textarea called facilities.
**Example**

```
{{ Form::textarea('facilities') }}
```

facilities

**including free WiFi, breakfast and newspapers, a concierge and Aquila Spa with a pool and gym**

And when i submit this form i want to generate the view in list like this

- free WiFi
- breakfast and newspaper
- concierge
- Aquila Spa
- pool
- gym

Is this possible in laravel any suggestion and help would be heartily appreciated

Comment: If it was just a comma separated list it would be a simple `explode()` to get an array and then a `foreach` to make the list but when you've got words like 'with a' 'and' you're going to have to write some logic to remove the unwanted words. Not easy. Natural language detection is tricky at best.

Comment: @Joe is totally right. Especially since you want to use `and` as a delimiter but not for `breakfast and newspapers`. Is there any logic behind this you can share with us?